# If property does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am filtering the data through arr.map() and then sendig that data to a React-Table, since my API returns several properties which i will not be using for now.

```js
const filteredPuntedIssues = this.state.puntedIssues.map(item => ({
  assignee: item ? item.assigneeName : 'Empty',
  id: item ? item.id : 'Empty',
  key: item ? item.key : 'Empty',
  type: item ? item.typeName : 'Empty',
  summary: item ? item.summary : 'Empty',
  storyPoints: item.estimateStatistic ? item.estimateStatistic.statFieldValue.value : '0',
}));
```

This works if any of the values are null, but if somewhere in my API one of those properties dont exist, it turns out to be empty, and i want to make it a string ex: "Does not Exists"

Comment: So you wanna replace the whole object with `"Does not exist"` if one of the props is empty?

Comment: like `item ? (item.id || 'Does not exist' ) : 'Empty',`

Comment: Thanks @JonasW. & @Chris G, maybe i didn´t explained as i should! 
`(item.id || 'Does not exist' )` was what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another ternary condition for that. For example :

```
assignee: item ? (item.assigneeName ? item.assigneeName : "Does not Exists") : 'Empty'
```

ou

```
assignee: item ? (item.assigneeName || "Does not Exists") : 'Empty'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const filteredPuntedIssues = this.state.puntedIssues.map(item => 
   ["assigneeName", "id", "key", "typeName", "summary", "storyPoints"].every(k => item[k])
   ? item
   : "Does not exist"
);
```